# using cp to print a text file

Tags: command-line, printing

I have 2 printers (both are "Generic Text-Only Printer")

1. The first one is connected directly to my laptop through a USB. This printer corresponds to a device /dev/usb/lp0. For this one I can print a file just by using either cp or lp

`$ cp textfile /dev/usb/lp0`

or

`$ lp -d "printer-name" textfile`

2. The second one is a network printer with an URI  "socket://192.168.0.123"
   Currently, I can only print a text file using the command lp

`$ lp -d "printer-name" textfile`

Is there any way I can use cp here? Just like the first printer
Something like

`$ cp textfile ...?`

If I can use cp, then I can just write directly to that file (/dev/usb/lp0) to print something from an application. Otherwise, I need to write to a text file first, then launch "lp ..." . This is a lot more cumbersome.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you very much

Comment: Probably you have to try `cat textfile > /dev/usb/lp0` or `lpr textfile`.

Answer (score 1):

Network connected printers require a network-aware application such as netcat to process a file.

nc printer_IP_or_host_name 9100 < printer-ready_file